# Ghostscript exec: PHP vs Python

Tags: php, python, ghostscript

I'm trying to execute a simple Ghostscript command to get number of PDF pages.
Here is PHP cmd:

```
$pages = 'sudo gs -q -dNODISPLAY -c "(' . $input . ') (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"';
```

Tried exec(), system(), shell_exec(), and passthru() - none return the stdout.

For s&g, I tried Python:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('sudo gs -q -dNODISPLAY -c "(/Users/me/Downloads/multi-page.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"')
```

Got output of 32.

Main goal is to get this to work in PHP - what am I missing?

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Check if your PHP user may use `sudo` and has a login shell. If it's a webserver on a Debian-like system, the user is most likely `www-data`. Which usually doesn't have a shell and isn't allowed to use `sudo`.

Comment: What's the value of `$input`? Also, are you sure apache2 or whatever can use sudo?

Comment: You're right, this is going through Apache2 - I removed the sudo part as I'm just reading from the file. When I execute through PHP-CLI it provides stdout, but not through apache2 server for some reason.

Comment: Value of input is just the multi page pdf.

Comment: Downvoted because of lack of research (or at least the research was not indicated). If you google PHP + Sudo, you will find lots of results. But your question does not indicate that you have read those results and have tried to apply the solutions. Now we're stuck here guessing. Also, you're not telling us how you're invoking PHP, what system you're on, or if there's anything in the error logs.

Comment: I removed sudo but still same problem. Invoking PHP through a Laravel route.

Comment: Check under which user your Apache runs (as I said, most likely `www-data` if it's Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/Aptosid), then check in `/etc/passwd` if that user has got a login shell like `/bin/bash`. Most likely he doesn't, and it's a good idea *not* to change that – unless you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

This was a function of the executable not being located, without any indication from PHP.
I went a roundabout way:

Python script:

```
>>> #!/usr/bin/python
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> input_file = sys.argv[1].replace("2>&1", "")
>>> num_pages = os.system('gs -q -dNODISPLAY -c "(' + input_file + ') (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"')

>>> print num_pages
```

PHP script envoking Python script:

```
$cmd_path = base_path('backend/misc/get_pdf_pages.py');
$pages_cmd = "python -u {$cmd_path} " . escapeshellarg($input) . " 2>&1";
exec($pages_cmd, $ret);
echo $ret[0];
```

Which resulted in: "sh: gs: command not found"

Thanks to that tip, I changed gs to /usr/local/bin/gs, that worked in Python, tried the same thing in PHP, worked in PHP. Lesson learned - use absolute paths to binaries.